# Inconsistent $PATH in VSCode integrated terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh

I've noticed that opening a particular folder (a node project) in a VSCode window adds more locations to $PATH in the integrated terminal. This has been a source of confusion when trying to manage node versions with nvm and finding that this particular project always ran under node 10 instead of a more recent version (`/Users/william/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/bin` was on the PATH for this project).

What could be special about this project to cause this behaviour?

---

### Notes:

When opening the integrated terminal in VSCode outside of this particular project, the PATH matches that of the macOS terminal.

This project is to develop an Azure static web app. The Azure Functions extension is used with nodejs to test the code locally.

The project has a .vscode folder for project configuration but I can't find anything related to  $PATH in there.

Comment: I deleted the project and re-cloned it from github. This seemed to "fix" the problem.

Comment: So, how about you close this question then?

Comment: @MarlonRichert I'd still like to know the answer

Comment: I just did `print -l - $path` in VS Code's integrated terminal and in macOS's Terminal app, and they both output the exact same values. Whatever is causing your `$path` to be modified, it's not VS Code itself that's doing it. Perhaps it's an extension you're using?